# Equivalent of DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH in Joda Time

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

What is the equivalent of Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH in Joda Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Joda-Time for a long time and I was searching this equivalent. But this equivalent is absent in Joda API.

Instead of this, ypu sould combine params `dayOfWeek`, `dayOfMonth` and `weekOfMonth`

Comment: Hi, can you provide some example how to achieve this functionality?